# TypeError: author is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

creating react AuthorQuiz app 
I have tow main file
1- AuthorQuiz.js
2- index.js
I have a problem with Turn component

AuthorQuiz.js

```
enter code here

function Turn({ author, books }) { 
return (
<div className="row turn" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
  <div className="col-4 offset-1">
    <img src={author.imageUrl} className="authorImage" alt="Author" />
  </div>
  <div className="col-6">
    {books.map((title) =>  <p>{title}</p>)}
  </div>
</div>);
    }

function AuthorQuiz(turnData) {
return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
        <Hero/>
        <Turn {...turnData}/>
        <Continue/>
        <Footer/>
        </div>
 );
}
```

index.js

```
enter code here
const authors = [
{
    name: 'mark Twin',
    imageUrl: 'images/authors/mark.jpg',
    imageSource: 'google wiki',
    books: ['The Advance of Finn']
 }
 ];

const state={
turnData:{
author:authors[0],
books:authors[0].books
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AuthorQuiz {...state}/>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

but when I run my code I get an error

TypeError: author is undefined
Turn
C:/Users/HP/Desktop/React pro/authorquiz/src/AuthorQuiz.js:18

Answer (score 0):

The AuthorQuiz component is getting the `turnData` variable as a prop. You should use the spread operator on the `props.turnData` variable instead.

```
function AuthorQuiz(props) {
  return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Hero/>
        <Turn {...props.turnData}/>
        <Continue/>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
  );
}
```

The props in the `AuthorQuiz` component look like this:

```
{
  turnData: {
    author: { .. },
    books: [ .. ]
  }
}
```

Your `Turn` component wants the author and books props, so you could do this in your `AuthorQuiz` component.

```
function AuthorQuiz(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Hero/>
      <Turn {...props.turnData} />
      {/* or */}
      <Turn author={props.turnData.author} books={props.turnData.books} />
      <Continue/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could also destructure the turnData prop in your component function directly. This makes it clear which props are being drilled down the `Turn` component without switching to multiple files.

```
function AuthorQuiz({ turnData: { author, books } }) {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Hero/>
      <Turn author={author} books={books} />
      <Continue/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use {state.turnData} instead of {...state}.

Because the result of {...state} is like this: {turnData: {…}}

So { author, books } can't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const state={
turnData:{
author:authors[0],
books:authors[0].books
 }
}

<AuthorQuiz {...state}/>
```

Spreading the state over the `AuthorQuiz` is equivalent to:

```
<AuthorQuiz turnData={state.turnData}/>
```

But in the `AuthorQuiz` component:

```js
function AuthorQuiz(turnData) {
return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
        <Hero/>
        <Turn {...turnData}/>
        <Continue/>
        <Footer/>
        </div>
 );
}
```

```js
function AuthorQuiz(turnData) {
...
  <Turn {...turnData}/>
...
```

is equivalent to

```js
function AuthorQuiz(props) {

...
  <Turn turnData={
props.turnData
}}/>
...
```

So you need to add brackets to spread `turnData` instead of `props`:

```js
function AuthorQuiz({ turnData }) {

...
  <Turn { ...turnData}}/>
...
```